# JAXB - marshal string with xml value without the value getting escaped

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm trying to marshal a String that contains xml. 
For example:

```
<articles>
 <article>
  <name>foo</name>
  <price>5</price>
 </article>
</articles
```

The result I get is always an escaped String:

```
&lt;articles&gt;&lt;article&gt;&lt;name&gt;foo&lt;/name&gt;&lt;price&gt;5&lt;/price&gt;&lt;/article&gt;&lt;/articles&gt;
```

I created a test which looks like this:

```
public class XmlTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Flex flex = new Flex();
        flex.setValueA("lalala");
        flex.setValueB("<articles><article><name>foo</name><price>5</price></article></articles>");

        JAXBElement<Flex> el = new JAXBElement(new QName("Blub"), flex.getClass(), flex);

        try {
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Flex.class);
            Marshaller marshaller = jaxbContext.createMarshaller();
            marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller.marshal(flex, System.out);

            JAXBContext jaxbContext2 = JAXBContext.newInstance(Flex.class);
            Marshaller marshaller2 = jaxbContext2.createMarshaller();
            marshaller2.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, true);
            marshaller2.marshal(el, System.out);
        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }

    @XmlRootElement(name = "foo")
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
    public static class Flex extends AuditableVo {

        @XmlElement(name = "valueA")
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String valueA;

        @XmlElement(name = "valueB")
        @Getter
        @Setter
        private String valueB;
    }
}
```

I've tried a lot of suggestions from stackoverflow, but none of them prevent the escaping. Trying a handler (for @XmlAnyElement) ends with "unable to marshal type 'java.lang.String' as an element because it is missing an @XmlRootElement".

I'm new to JAXB, so if anyone could help me get through this, you would make my day.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use XML in XML you should use CDATA, [see CDATA Sections](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml/#sec-cdata-sect)
. Anything else won't work when marshalling with JAXB.

Comment: Thank you, I'll look into this. At the moment I just copied the tag into the string -> flex.setValueB("<![CDATA[<greeting>Hello, world!</greeting>]]>"); and it still escapes the value.